# How to use Java Socket with Runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, jakarta-ee

I want to call a function `cycle()` that do something for every some x second.
At this time i can call it only when it has a request from client.

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable {

    private static final int PORT = 9001;
    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    private static class Handler extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {

            cycle();          

            try {

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in.readLine();
                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (names) {
                        if (!names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
                writers.add(out);
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {

                if (name != null) {
                    names.remove(name);
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, code below is work when i remove `Handle` class from my code.
My problem is i can't combine them together, please help or suggest. Many thanks.

```
private void cycle() {

    //do something
}

@Override
public void run() {

    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true) {

        cycle();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep < 0) {
            sleep = 2;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you try to start a separate thread for the cycle function before call listen to the socket.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
    //start separate thread to keep loop....
    new Thread(new ChatServer()).start();
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. You have to ask Marcus in the comments.